# Automapper project from joined tables in linq

Tags: linq, automapper

I am joining two tables in LINQ and using AutoMapper 9 to project the result into a DTO object.

```
var result = (from s in _db.TableA
                join d in _db.TableB on s.Id equals d.ForeignKeyId  
                select s).ProjectTo<MyDTO>(mapper).ToList();
```

This works fine except I need one property from the joined table d to be mapped into the MyDTO object as well.

Is there a way to tell AutoMapper to project properties from both tables?

Comment: `ProjectTo` works best with FK entity properties, no id-s.

Comment: Hi @LucianBargaoanu thanks for your reply. I was thinking more in general terms, is there a way to map properties from more than one table in linq with Automapper?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but for best results, work with AM, not against it. And the way to do it is to have FK entity properties.